# Hibernate @OneToMany exception while adding new entities

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, java-8

I have two entities in MySql Database. First is *Users* entity and second is *Movies*. I set relation `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`. I mean, one user can own multiple movies and several movies can belong to one user.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id"})})
public class Movies {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "movie_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "expirationTime")
    private DateTime expirationTime;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Users userId;




@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class Users {
    

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = true)
    private String phoneNumber;
    

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Builder.Default
    private Set<Movies> movies = new HashSet<>(0);
```

I could add one entity of Movies per User. When I want to add another row for this same user (adding new movie) I receive exception like this:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '7' for key 'movies.UKno13de9csa3gf2das1j6dsa12
```

Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: I think the problem is your UniqueConstraint. Does removing it solve the issue?

Comment: No, it didnt resolve the problem

Comment: Did you remove the constraint from DB?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt yes

Comment: I will recreate db as was in other suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Drop all the tables directly from database and let hibernate recreate the tables as your old constraint can still be there.
- Remove the `uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id"})`
- It tries to enforce a `movie` record can only have `one unique`  user row

Answer (score 2):

The issue was @UniqueConstraint. I had to restore DB before changes were applied in structure. Removing constraint in DB doesn't help. So as suggested I removed from code this annotation and let hibernate do the job. Now I can add multiple entities for single user.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing zero to the set? I suspect, that zero is causing the issue here.

```
private Set<Movies> movies = new HashSet<>(0);
```

Remove the zero and it will work.

```
private Set<Movies> movies = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: No, problem still occured

Comment: Ok...please show the code how do you save entity. Also remove constraints and try to drop constraints for testing purpose. Can add it later.

Comment: I'm restoring my DB before changes in entity. It will take a while so if suggestions won't help I will post code how entity is being saved

Comment: Sure.no problem

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of unique constraint is wrong. Having `@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id"})}` means there can only be one movie row with user 7. You need to add new constraint and set it on columns id, user_id. Also drop old one.

```
ALTER TABLE movies
ADD CONSTRAINT movie_user_uq
UNIQUE (id, user_id);
```